# Is there some syntax to unpack a tuple but have an alternate value if one of the values is falsy?

Tags: python, tuples

Example I might have:

```
x = None
y = x or 0
```

In a tuple, am I able to somehow unpack the tuple but give some default value if a falsy value is found?  Example:

```
values = (1, None)
one or 0, two or 0 = values
```

I know that my solution doesn't work but I was wondering if there is some one-line syntax that does.

Comment: nope, there isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a generator expression:

```
one, two = (v or 0 for v in values)
```

Comment: I think the idea is you could do something like `one or 1, two or 2 = values`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. But you have to do it on the other side of the =

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If so, we could do `one, two = (v or d for v, d in zip(values, (1, 2)))`. But that's already not nice and I'd probably do it in some non-oneliner way.